# Sample size analysis for pearson's R - corrected for multiple comparison

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power

I want to determine what sample size I need to be able to detect a strong correlation ($r \geq 0.5$). I found [this nice online calculator](http://www.sample-size.net/correlation-sample-size/), which tells me I would need a sample size of 7 with $\beta = 0.8$ and $\alpha = 0.05$.

Now, I am looking at the correlation of time spent doing one of multiple behaviors, and activity in a number of brain regions. Meaning that I won't just be determining one correlation coefficient, but somewhere around 30.

Is there any way to take that into account when estimating my required sample size?

Comment: I think either you are mis-reading it or the calculator is wrong for that is not an adequate sample size for the parameters you mention.

Comment: How do you determine what is and isn't an adequate sample size for the parameters I mentioned?

Comment: I was basing my comment on the confidence interval for $r$ which for 0.5 with $n=7$ is from -0.41 to 0.91 indicating that with only seven data points we know almost nothing about $r$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sample size calculation for correlation study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154478/sample-size-calculation-for-correlation-study)

Comment: $\beta$ = 0.8 is the wrong choice.  You want it to be 0.2 or 0.1 .   That gives R of 29.